# Get all child objects in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a such model:

```
case class Product(id:String, nextVersion:Option[Product] = None)
```

Is it possible to get all versions of product? I can use while:

```
def getAllVersions(product: Product) = {

  var allVersions = List[Product]()
  var actualProduct = product
  while (actualProduct != null) {
    allVersions :+= actualProduct
    actualProduct = actualProduct.nextVersion.orNull
  }

  allVersions
}
```

but maybe there is some better way of doing this, more functional?

For example for:

```
Product("1", Some(Product("2", Some(Product("3", None)))))
```

I want to get list of three products "1", "2", "3".

Comment: Absolutely unclear what are you asking about

Comment: "I can use while" - Maybe illustrate your question by showing us that approach.

Comment: Should this question really be tagged playframework-2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you mean that you want to get a Seq of the IDs from a Product chain, like so:

```
scala> case class Product(id:String, nextVersion:Option[Product] = None)
defined class Product

scala> val p = Product("1", Some(Product("2", Some(Product("3", None)))))
p: Product = Product(1,Some(Product(2,Some(Product(3,None)))))

scala> def toList(p:Product): List[String] = p match {
         case Product(id, None)       => List(id)
         case Product(id, Some(next)) => id :: toList(next)
       }
toList: (p: Product)List[String]

scala> toList(p)
res2: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

A tail-recursive version would be more efficient and immune to stack overflows:

```
scala> def toList(p:Product) = {
         @tailrec def loop(p: Product, soFar: List[String]): List[String] =
           p match {
            case Product(id, None)       =>            id :: soFar
            case Product(id, Some(next)) => loop(next, id :: soFar)
           }
         loop(p, Nil).reverse
       }
toList: (p: Product)List[String]

scala> toList(p)
res4: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Although we might be better off doing it with a `Vector`: fewer objects created, no need to reverse at the end, and much more efficient if the caller wants to access the result non-sequentially.  But let's return a `Seq` so we can change the type later if we want to:

```
scala> def toList(p:Product): Seq[String] = {
         @tailrec def loop(p: Product, soFar: Vector[String]): Vector[String] =
           p match {
             case Product(id, None)       =>            soFar :+ id
             case Product(id, Some(next)) => loop(next, soFar :+ id)
           }
         loop(p, Vector())
       }
toList: (p: Product)Seq[String]

scala> toList(p)
res5: Seq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

The following version is shorter and not *explicitly* recursive -- the call back to `toList` is done from within `Option#map`.  However, this currently means that tail-call optimization will not be done on the recursion (the Scala compiler *can't* do it, and the JVM currently does not do it), so this could cause a stack overflow if the Product version chain is long enough.  And it will be less efficient than the code above.

```
scala> def toList(p:Product): List[String] =
         p.id :: (p.nextVersion map toList getOrElse Nil)
toList: (p: Product)List[String]

scala> toList(p)
res1: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

You could define and use an `Iterator[Product]`, like so:

```
scala> implicit def productIterator(firstP: Product) = new Iterator[Product] {
         private var optP = Option(firstP)
         def hasNext = optP.isDefined
         def next =
           if (hasNext) {
             val p = optP.get
             optP = p.nextVersion
             p
           } else {
             sys error "read past end of Iterator[Product]"
           }
       }
productIterator: (firstP: Product)Iterator[Product]

scala> (p map (_.id)).toList
res22: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

But since your data structure is recursive, the code to traverse it has to either be recursive (explicitly or implicitly) or use mutable variables (as the `Iterator` does).

Comment: How about not using recursion?

Comment: Recursion is core to functional programming.